# Python - remove excessive html tags

Tags: python, html

So I'm currently having this text:

```
<i>This article is written </i><a href="http://google.com"><i>TEST</i></a><i>.</i>
```

I think this is a good HTML, however, I want to clean it up, remove all the excessive `<i>` tags and simplify it to a single `<i>` tag:

```
<i>This article is written <a href="http://google.com">TEST</a>.</i>
```

I tried to clean it up myself, but I'd need to look ahead for the text, and haven't had much success with this. Is there a package I can use or a way that I can do it or I'd have to manually do it?

Thank you

Comment: I don't know of anything that would do this. The two html snippets are not equivalent (for example if there's a css rule `i a` it will match the second but not the first), so you would have to clarify exactly which semantic changes you consider significant and which are not.

Answer (score 0):

The use of an HTML parser is definitely the most reliable solution. It would be able to cope with the tags split across many lines.

The following will solve your example, but probably not much more...

```
def OuterI(text):
    outer = re.search("(.*?)(\<i\>.*<\/i\>)(.*)", text)

    if outer:
        return "%s<i>%s</i>%s" % (outer.group(1), re.sub(r"(\<\/?[iI]\>)", "", outer.group(2)), outer.group(3))
    else:
        return text

print OuterI('<i>This article is written </i><a href="http://google.com"><i>TEST</i></a><i>.</i>')
print OuterI('text before <i>This article is written </i><a href="http://google.com"><i>TEST</i></a><i>.</i> text after')
```